# redirect all sub url to primary url

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a wordpress site running on apache. I need to redirect `domain.com/examplepage/*` to `domain.com/examplepage`

so as an example

`domain.com/examplepage/randomstring/randomstring`
world go to
`domain.com/examplepage`

I've tried to google how to do this but cant find a way. I'm sure it's because I just don't know how to search for the correct thing. I'm willing to use wordpress plugin, .htaccess, or apache config. Whatever works.

Comment: All the basic url rewrites cover directing a single url to another or a folder to another. I have not found one that talks about redirecting from a sub folder to a parent. When I try to follow them it seems to get stuck into a loop of recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can see many, many answers to this here on SO. Did you check the "Related" section on the right hand side here?

Anyway, here is what you are probably looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?examplepage/.+ /examplepage [END]
```

The above implements an internal rewrite. In case you really want an external redirection instead this would be the variant:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?examplepage/.+ /examplepage [R=301]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup, certainly you will need to add another rewriting condition to break an endless rewriting loop.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you very much. Trying to follow the rewrite tutorials I found I was getting into strange recursion problems. I will accept your answer once the timer allows me :)

Comment: Sure, rewriting loops can occur, one has to keep that in mind. Nothing strange about that, actually. Most likely you simply rewrote the base path to itself and used the old `L` flag instead of `END`.